# Program not reading txt file

Tags: java, netbeans, file-io

I am a beginner Java student, working on our first class assignment.
In this assignment, I need to read a `txt` file, and fill an array with its contents, first space in the array per line.

My professor gave us code to do this, but I keep getting an error that the file cannot be read each time I try.
I am using Netbeans 8, on a Mac, and the file `States.Fall2014.txt` is located in the `src` folder, with all of my java classes.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: States.Fall2014.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at main.main(main.java:21)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the code I have. I have only included the code that pertains to opening the file, as I'm sure you have no wish to be spammed with the other classes.
The commented code during the trimming is to echo print, to make sure the file is being read in properly (not currently needed since the file isn't being read in at all).

```
import java.io.*;

public class main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        StateCollection Sdriver = new StateCollection(50);
         //Sdriver = new StateCollection(50);
        //Creates object of collection class
         FileReader fr= new FileReader("States.Fall2014.txt");
         BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader (fr);
          String inputString;  
      String stateName;
          String stateCapital;
          String stateAbbrev;
          int statePop;
          String stateRegion;
          int stateRegionNum;

          inputString = br1.readLine();
            while (inputString != null)
         {
           stateName = inputString.substring(1, 15).trim();
           //System.out.println("stateName read in was: " + stateName);
           stateCapital = inputString.substring(16, 30).trim();
           //System.out.println(“stateCapital read in was: “ + stateCapital);
           stateAbbrev = inputString.substring(31, 32).trim();
           //System.out.println(“stateAbbrev read in was: “ + stateAbbrev);
           statePop = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(33, 40));
           //System.out.println(“statePop read in was: “ + statePop);
           stateRegion = inputString.substring(41, 55).trim();
           //System.out.println(“stateRegion read in was: “ + stateRegion);
           stateRegionNum = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(56));
           //System.out.println(“stateRegionNum read in was: “ + stateRegionNum);
           //Code to create object
            inputString = br1.readLine();    // read next input line.
         }
         br1.close();     //Close input file being read
```

Comment: Why don't you hardcode the full path? You can right click the text file and copy the path from properties.

Comment: I'll need to zip the file and send it to my Professor, so won't that break the path if I did the hardcoded path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`FileReader fr= new FileReader("States.Fall2014.txt");`

to

`FileReader fr= new FileReader("src/States.Fall2014.txt");`

**or** move the file up one level to the project directory.

Comment: Adding /src worked. Thank you!
(Will marked as Answered when it lets me)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the TXT file is in the right folder/area.

You shouldn't have it with your class, as the other answer states, you need it in the root folder.

Comment: He says it in the same folder as the class

Comment: Make sure you define the location of the file.  This varies when using different IDE's.

Comment: Sorry about that, missed my eye.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file up one level, to the same as the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

The src directory is not (necessarily) the directory the .class file is in. Make sure States.Fall2014.txt is on the class-path.